# Animating a line moving on a Canvas

Tags: java, android

I've made this fairly simple View. It's supposed to animate a red line that travels from left to right over a period of time (`DURATION`). It should update it's position every `DELAY`, so that you can adjust the animation to be more smoother if you would want that. It should be noted that I'm testing this on the emulator. Well, if I increase `DELAY` then the animation finishes faster, even though it should have no effect on the total animation time. Am I simply animating too fast, hogging all the resources? Or is my math off?

```
public class AnimView extends View {

    // Animation duration in milliseconds
    private static final int DURATION = 4000;

    // Update frame every delay (in milliseconds)
    private static final int DELAY = 10;

    private int pos;
    private long lastTick;
    private Paint paint;

    public AnimView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        pos = 0;
        lastTick = 0;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTick >= DELAY) {
            // Calculate a new position for the line
            pos += (int) (((double) DELAY / DURATION) * getWidth());

            lastTick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        canvas.drawRect(pos, 0, pos + 1, getHeight(), paint);

        if(pos < getWidth()) {
            // Position is still below getWidth, keep animating
            postInvalidate();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where do you change lastTick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be updating lastTick in the if statement:

```
 long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 if(currentTime - lastTick >= DELAY) {
   // Calculate a new position for the line
   pos += (int) (((double) DELAY / DURATION) * getWidth());
   lastTick = currentTime;
 }
```

Otherwise you will draw each time after DELAY passes. So when you increase DELAY, less drawing happens and so the program finishes faster.

Comment: Yeah I updated the code, it looked like the problem was the same but some further testing prooved it was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add some additional color to this thread, this is a well known problem in game development. You can find lots of resources on it if you search for "Fixed time step vs Variable time step", for example:  http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

The gist of it is that the speed of your animation is directly tied to your frame rate at the moment. This is why in the old NES megaman games, you'd have periods of slow down when there were lots of enemies on the screen at once (because the CPU was busier calculating all the data for those entities, so each frame took longer to process).

There are two ways around this problem:

1. Move to a variable time step where you multiply each movement by the amount of time that progressed between each frame of animation. That way, when that amount changes for any reason, your animation looks the same.
2. Separate the update and draw phases so that you can control the time diff that is passed into the update method, regardless of how fast you're drawing.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the beginning of a game pet-project so your comment is very relevant.